issues with 22.04.1 LTS
after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS , main units stopped working, everything I save on the desktop disappears, ubuntu software does not load and some programs and applications disappeared
also before starting there start a checking system about 5 min !!
how can I repair this?

Open a terminal, and install all the available updates
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade

If Ubuntu's default packages (e.g.ubuntu app center/firefox) are still missing, you can install all of them with
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^

